# Polyglossia + Right-to-left language breaks tufte-book footnotes and sidenotes

Tags: xetex, footnotes, polyglossia, right-to-left, tufte-book

I'm trying to write a document with tufte-book and polyglossia for a bit of hebrew inside english text. But the sidenote and footnote commands are not working.

```
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{libertine} % Font for hebrew text
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\let\XeLaTeX\relax
\let\XeTeX\relax
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew} % Deleting this line works
\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
    hi\sidenote{bye}
\end{document}
```

If the second language isn't right-to-left it works perfectly; but, if it is, suddenly the sidenote and footnote commands break. It says *Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). ^^Ihi\sidenote{bye}* and *Missing number, treated as zero. ^^Ihi\sidenote{bye}* Is there anything I can do?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the class with the bidi option, then it will changes some of its commands:

```
\documentclass[bidi]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{libertine} % Font for hebrew text
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\let\XeLaTeX\relax
\let\XeTeX\relax
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew} % Deleting this line works

\begin{document}
    hi\sidenote{bye}
\end{document}
```